# How can I create a file when my c program exits?

Tags: c, shell, signals, signal-processing

I am working on an assignment where I am implementing the unix history command in a shell.  In my program I have written a signal handler for SIGINT.  When a user enters (ctrl)(c) their history is displayed.

When my program terminates I need to store the history in a file.  Is there an easy way to detect when my program has exited?  Or do I need to have a signal handler for every type of signal ((ctrl)(d), pausebreak, etc).

Comment: One other option is to ensure that your history is up to date on disk at all times (within the limits of the system calls you use).  When you go to execute a command, you launch the command and write the history file.  Then, if the program is terminated, the history is up to date on disk, ready for the next time the shell is run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`atexit()` is probably what you're looking for, see the manual page: [man 3 atexit](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/atexit.3.html)

Usage is something like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

static void save_the_file(void)
{
    /* ... */
}

int main()
{
    atexit(save_the_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Another option is to use the `destructor` attribute (GCC/Clang):

```
static __attribute__((destructor)) void save_the_file(void)
{
     /* your code */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

atexit is that. But if you want to follow SIGKILL also, you need watcher-process that call waitpid().